# Structured data testing tool is showing preview for rich result, but rich result test says "Page not eligible for rich results known by this test"

Tags: google-search, rich-snippets, google-rich-snippets-tool, rich-cards

Google's [structured data testing tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool/u/0/) is showing a preview for the type `http://schema.org/Course`, but the [rich result test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results) shows

> Page not eligible for rich results known by this test

[image]

Any idea what's the problem? No errors and the rich results test even showed the the same page eligible for result results, but after that shows not eligible.

Comment: Google says that it shows special (rich) search results based on `Course` markup: https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/course

Comment: I am facing the same issue! Did it work well?

Comment: Sorry I couldn't find the solution